# How to reduce the width of the slider in ngzorro? Currently it occupies the entire screen

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

<nz-slider nzRange [(ngModel)]="value2" nzIncluded [nzDisabled]="disabled">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "nz-form" and wrap "nz-slider" with form control and reduce the width by [nzSpan]

```
<form nz-form>
    <nz-form-item>
      <nz-form-label [nzSpan]="6" nzFor="slider">Slider</nz-form-label>
      <nz-form-control [nzSpan]="14">
         <nz-slider nzRange [(ngModel)]="value2" nzIncluded 
                [nzDisabled]="disabled">
       </nz-form-control>
     </nz-form-item >
</form>
```